# multiple pages should read data from central webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to develop a information based website to showcase list of automation projects are completed by my team. Idea is to create 3 webpages

Page1, will have information about the automation projects delivered to the clients (For clients to see)
Page2,  will have the metrics like time took before automation and time after automation etc. This will be presented in the bar and circular graphs (For management to see)
Page3, This should act like central page and data entered here should reflect in other pages. This will be in table format

Problem here is I am struggling to write code such that page1 and page 2 will automatically read corresponding data from page3. Any help with code, links or suggestions is highly appreciated

```
enter code here

here is our code:



    html 1: dynamically added rows with  edit and save delete buttons  to a table 
           <body>
           <div class="marginT5 float_left"><img src="black.png" align="right" 
           width="260" height="100" 
            /></div>
          <div class="main_navline">
          <div >&nbsp;</div>

           <div  id ="test" title="" class="manu" align="center" > </div> 


           <div >&nbsp;</div>


           <form onsubmit="passing()" id="myForm" method="get" >
           <table  class="data_table" id="data_table" >


           <tr>
           <th>Level of the task</th>
           <th>Task</th>
    <th>Automation ID</th>
    <th>Activity</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="new_name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="new_type"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="new_url"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="new_description"></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="add" onclick="add_row();" value="Add Row"> 
          </td>
           </tr>




    </table>

    </form>

    html 2: the url and description of each row  entered in htm1 need to be displayed in html2

    <body >
    <div class="marginT5 float_left"><img src="black.png" align="right" width="260" height="100" 
  /></div>
    <div class="main_navline">&nbsp;</div>
    <div >&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="inner_wrapper">
    <div class="manu" align="center" >TEAM</div> 

    <div class="w3-container">

    <form name="form1" method="get">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="here"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>

    ourjavascript:


    function edit_row(no)

    {
          document.getElementById("save_button"+no).disabled = false;
         document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).disabled = true;

    /*  document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).style.display="none";

     document.getElementById("save_button"+no).style.display="block"; */

     var name=document.getElementById("name_row"+no);
     var url=document.getElementById("url_row"+no);
     var type=document.getElementById("type_row"+no);
      var description=document.getElementById("description_row"+no);

     var name_data=name.innerHTML;
     var url_data=url.innerHTML;
     var type_data=type.innerHTML;
         var description_data=description.innerHTML;
     name.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='name_text"+no+"' value='"+name_data+"'>";
     url.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='url_text"+no+"' value='"+url_data+"'>";
     type.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='type_text"+no+"' value='"+type_data+"'>";
      description.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='description_text"+no+"' value='"+description_data+"'>";
    }

    function save_row(no)
    {
     var name_val=document.getElementById("name_text"+no).value;
     var url_val=document.getElementById("url_text"+no).value;
     var type_val=document.getElementById("type_text"+no).value;
    var description_val=document.getElementById("description_text"+no).value;

     document.getElementById("name_row"+no).innerHTML=name_val;
     document.getElementById("url_row"+no).innerHTML=url_val;
     document.getElementById("type_row"+no).innerHTML=type_val;
    document.getElementById("description_row"+no).innerHTML=description_val;

     document.getElementById("save_button"+no).disabled = true;
         document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).disabled = false;


    /*  document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).style.display="block";
     document.getElementById("save_button"+no).style.display="none"; */
    }

    function delete_row(no)
    {
     document.getElementById("row"+no+"").outerHTML="";
    }

    function add_row()
    {
     var new_name=document.getElementById("new_name").value;
     var new_url=document.getElementById("new_url").value;
     var new_type=document.getElementById("new_type").value;
     var new_description=document.getElementById("new_description").value;

     var table=document.getElementById("data_table");
     var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
     var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'><td id='name_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_name+"</td><td id='url_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_url+"</td><td id='type_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_type+"</td><td id='description_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_description+"</td><td><input type='button' id='edit_button"+table_len+"' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' id='save_button"+table_len+"' value='Save' class='save'   disabled onclick='save_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'></td></tr>";

     document.getElementById("new_name").value="";
     document.getElementById("new_url").value="";
     document.getElementById("new_type").value="";
     document.getElementById("new_description").value="";



    }
```

Comment: we are happy to help but need to see some code you already written. we can't provide you with a finished product, but we can help you with specific problems. we first need to know what you already know.

Comment: You'll need to make your JavaScript the source of data. For example, let's say you will list a set of automation projects in page1, and summaries of these projects in another page, then you'll need to store your projects as JS objects and use them in whatever pages you desire. This could be done using vanilla JavaScript, but it's much easier to use a framework. Read about **Single Page Applications (SPA)**.

Comment: You can use templating engines in whatever sever side lang you're using or if you're using a frontend framwork also this job is quite easy

Comment: HI Ammar, May I know what frontend framwork I can use. I am new to web development and this is my first project.

Comment: If you  using pure HTML and JS, then you can use `localStorage` to persist values across.  Simply assign any value to local storage by `localStorage.data = "your value" ` and retrieve in page 3 by ` var data = localStorage.data ;`   more on local storage is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) ,

Comment: Thanks Karthickj25. I have written my webapp in php using codeigniter framework. Thanks all